# limiting the length of output of a random string generator

Tags: javascript, random, output

My random generator makes names predominately to the large side. From what I read that can be a factor if you use `.round`, `.ceil` or `.floor`. It also it supposed to make a name no smaller than 3 and no larger than 13.

After adding the title to the name, some of the names were 2 and 14 and such, so I modified it again. Am I going the wrong way about this?

```
var nameLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 3) + 3); /* min 3 max 13*/
var compareLetter = 0;
var randomLetter = "";
var randomName = "";
var capitolLetter = "";
var checkLetter = 0;
var nameTitle = "XXX"; /* titles add _ between title and name*/
var nameLetters = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
    ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"],
    ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
];
if (nameTitle !== "") { /* my attempt to subtract title length +1 from name length if over 13*/
    nameLength = nameLength + (nameTitle.length + 1);
    if (nameLength > 13) {
        nameLength = nameLength - (nameLength - 13);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    randomLetter = nameLetters[compareLetter][Math.floor(Math.random() * nameLetters[compareLetter].length)];
    checkLetter = nameLetters[1].indexOf(randomLetter);
    if (checkLetter > -1) { /* my version of keeping consanants and vowels from stacking up */
        compareLetter = 2;
    } else {
        compareLetter = 1;
    }
    if (randomName.length < 1) { /* my version to keep first letter capitolized*/
        capitolLetter = randomLetter.toUpperCase();
        randomName = randomName + capitolLetter;
    } else {
        randomName = randomName + randomLetter;
    }
}
if (nameTitle !== "") {
    alert(nameTitle + "_" + randomName);
} else {
    alert(randomName);
}
alert(nameLength);
alert(randomName.length);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: why did i get voted down, I asked a question, showed my working example, and described the situation, and I lose a point for that? and not to sound all defensive, but why is it everyone of my friends and I who post anything on here instantly get edited by the same people but these people editing our posts and voting us down never answer any of our posts.

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly your question is. Try to keep it short and simple. (e.g. post only few lines with expected result and actual result)